# How to tell if connection failed with Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I need to notify a user if they fail to connect to Firebase. Is this what the onCancelled() is for? Given the asynchrous nature of Firebase, I can't just wait for it to finish and see if nothing is loaded.

Comment: What defines "fail to connect" for your users? Firebase will automatically try to connect and retry (with progressive back-off). Even in good connectivity scenarios it may take seconds to connect and it regularly takes multiple tries. Keep in mind that most operations will continue to work fine during intermittent connectivity loss. I'd recommend [listening for `.info/connected`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state) and show that to the user as an indication if they're connected to the Firebase servers or not.

Comment: See [offline capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html)